# enzyme test contains for container

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, jestjs, enzyme

Does it make sense to test a component / element exist in a container?

I have this node

```
<div className="App">
  <input type="text" onChange={[undefined]} />
  <button onClick={[undefined]}>
    Add
  </button>
</div>
```

But why the test failed?

```
const wrapper = shallow(<App />);
console.log(wrapper.debug())
expect(
  wrapper.contains('<input type="text" onChange={()=>{}} />')
).toBeTruthy();
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/rjl3p727wm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two reasons for this:

1. The `contains` function expects a ReactNode or Nodes to be passed in and not a selector, this means we have to get rid of the quotes.
2. `()=>{}` is not equal to `undefined` which is the value inside App component.

Incorporating these changes:

```
expect(
  wrapper.contains(<input type="text" onChange={undefined} />)
).toBeTruthy();
```

[A fork of codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/4lvvv6ow89)

Comment: thanks for the correction. In my experience I always have to defined `onChange={undefined} `, coz in a node, it usually will have many props of function, how to avoid that? One way is to avoid using contains, maybe can use `.find('inputClass')`